# Convert Grid View Rows To Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net

### Hi, i want to (Rotate / Flip / Transpose) Grid view `Rows` in to `Columns`

Here is the Grid view with Data Source

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="faculty_name" HeaderText="Teacher Name" SortExpression="faculty_name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="att_date" HeaderText="Attendance Date" SortExpression="att_date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
  <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="active" HeaderText="Present" SortExpression="active" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DevdapSchool %>" SelectCommand="SELECT FacultyAttendance.att_date, FacultyAttendance.active, Faculty.faculty_name FROM FacultyAttendance INNER JOIN Faculty ON FacultyAttendance.teacher_id = Faculty.faculty_id WHERE (FacultyAttendance.faculty_id = @faculty_id) AND (FacultyAttendance.school_id = @school_id) ORDER BY FacultyAttendance.att_date">

 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:SessionParameter Name="faculty_id" SessionField="faculty_id" />
  <asp:SessionParameter Name="school_id" SessionField="school_id" />
 </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This Gridview display Monthly Attendance of Teacher like this.
[image]

I want to display result like this..
[image]

Comment: You can get the data in the required form from SQL server using Pivot. Then this can be directly bound to the gridview. Hope this helps https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/

Comment: Can you please help me with my query.

Comment: Please provide the SQL query you are using.

Comment: SELECT FacultyAttendance.att_date, FacultyAttendance.active, Faculty.faculty_name FROM FacultyAttendance INNER JOIN Faculty ON FacultyAttendance.teacher_id = Faculty.faculty_id WHERE (FacultyAttendance.faculty_id = @faculty_id) AND (FacultyAttendance.school_id = @school_id) ORDER BY FacultyAttendance.att_date

Comment: Is it a monthly report? I need to show only 31 days right?

Comment: yes the attendance display on monthly basis

Comment: Please check this. Don't have SQL at the moment. Query is not tested by executing it. Still I hope this will help.   SELECT
    *
FROM
(SELECT FacultyAttendance.att_date as attdate, FacultyAttendance.active as Active, Faculty.faculty_name as Name FROM FacultyAttendance INNER JOIN Faculty ON FacultyAttendance.teacher_id = Faculty.faculty_id WHERE (FacultyAttendance.faculty_id = @faculty_id) AND (FacultyAttendance.school_id = @school_id) ORDER BY FacultyAttendance.att_date) source
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Active)
    FOR attdate
    IN ( /*Mention all the dates in a month*/ )
) AS pvtMonth

Comment: This query display this error see here http://prnt.sc/njddu4

Comment: Please check the documentation